# Jquery fullcalendar display end date in agendaDay view when we select multiple dates from month view

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

I am implementing jquery fullcalendar in my php website. i want to make multiple selection for date. After selecting multiple dates automatically jump to agendaDay view Where i can select different time. please help me to solve this issue.Please someone tell me is it possible to select multiple dates in month view , after selecting it will jump to agendaDay view. I need end date in agendaday view so that i can add it in database. Suppose i am seleting dates from "03-02-2015" to "07-02-2015" in month view. after selecting it is jumping to day view where it is giving only "03-02-2015". not displaying "07-02-2015". i need this end date to add in my database so that i can define my schedule is from 3 feb to 7 feb.

This is my code for jump from month to day view

```
select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {           
            if (view.name=='month') {
                var d = new Date(); 
                var month = new Array();
                month[0] = "01";
                month[1] = "02";
                month[2] = "03";
                month[3] = "04";
                month[4] = "05";
                month[5] = "06";
                month[6] = "07";
                month[7] = "08";
                month[8] = "09";
                month[9] = "10";
                month[10] = "11";
                month[11] = "12";
                var curr_date = d.getDate();
                var curr_month = month[d.getMonth()];
                var curr_year = d.getFullYear(); 
                if (curr_date < 10) {
                     curr_date = "0" + curr_date;
                }
                var curdate = curr_year + '-' + curr_month + '-' + curr_date;

                if(start.format() < curdate)
                {
                    alert('You cannot fix schedule for past date');
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', start, end);
                }
            } else { 

                var start = start.format(); 
                var end = end.format(); 

                fee_add("Today Schedule",start, end);
            }
        },
```

Comment: So you want it to not jump to day-view when you select a range, right?

Comment: No, i want to jump to day view. i just want starting and ending date in day view. suppose my starting date is 9 feb 2015 and end date is 13 feb 2015. Now i am getting only starting date (9 feb 2015) in day view. i want 13 feb 2015 also in day view

Comment: http://fullcalendar.io/ this is the link from where i am using calendar

Comment: You want the text on the event to show "9 feb 2015 - 13 feb 2015"?

Answer (score 0):

### Display date range on multi-day event in agendaDay view

Using the [`eventRender`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) callback, you can fully customize how events are displayed.

```js
eventRender: function (event, element, view ) {
    if(view.name == 'agendaDay'){ // If day view
        element.find('.fc-time').remove(); // Remove the original time element
        element.prepend( // Add start and end
            "<span>" + event.start.format('MMM D') + // Format however you want
            "-</span><span>" + event.end.format('MMM D') + "</span>");
    }
},
```

And your [`select`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_callback/) function is needlessly complicated. Make use of the fact that all dates in fullcalendar are [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) objects.

```js
select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view) {
    if (view.name == 'month') {
        if (start.isBefore(moment())) { // moment() creates a date object with the current date
            alert('You cannot fix schedule for past date');
            return;
        } else {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', start, end);
        }
    }
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', [{ // This might be different for you
                                                   // but you need to actually add the new event somehow
        title: "new event",
        start: start,
        end: end
    }]);
}
```

And here is a working **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/q8moq0wt/8/)**.